# How can I work out if multiple dates are within a date range

Tags: r

I have a list of start and end dates and I wish to work out which of these fall into my dates (these just the last 3 dates/days in this instance). If any dates between the start and end date are within the last 3 days then I want to keep these

```
 myDates = c(20240320, 20240319, 20240318)

datesToSearch
itemNo             start    end
241             20240311 20240317
242             20240316 20240317
243             20240319 20240321
244             20240318 20240324
300             20240318 20240324
```

Here I just with to return a df with the data that matches what im looking for, in this case

```
correctdatesToSearch
itemNo             start    end
243             20240319 20240321
244             20240318 20240324
300             20240318 20240324
```

Comment: Why not store your dates as actual dates rather than integers representing dates? It would be much easier that way.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

It's much easier if you convert your dates to actual date objects rather than using integers to represent dates. The format you are using is easily converted using `lubridate::ymd`. We can do this on the fly, also using the `lubridate` functions `interval` and `%within%` to find out which rows include one or more of your dates between their start and end dates, then filtering out the result:

```r
library(lubridate)

df[ymd(myDates) |>
    sapply(\(x) x %within% interval(ymd(df$start), ymd(df$end))) |>
    apply(1, any),] 
#>   itemNo    start      end
#> 3    243 20240319 20240321
#> 4    244 20240318 20240324
#> 5    300 20240318 20240324
```